# Working with ant namespace / directory structure

Tags: ant, build-process, build-automation

I'm working with ant on linux using the command line.  I've got a simple build step with javac.  This compiles correctly but it creates a directory structure under build like my namespace.

ie: ./build/com/crosse/samplespace/SampleProgram.class

How can I get this output into one directory (where it's easier to call java on it).

I tried

```
 <target name="output" depends="compile">
            <copy todir="${output}">
                    <fileset dir="${build}" includes="**/*.class"/>
            </copy>
 </target>
```

but that repeats the same thing in my output directory.  How can I use ant to get everything into a single directory?

Alternatively how could I use an ant step to copy another file into the root of that path (an apache commons configuration file)?

Edit: This is mainly a convenience factor, I get tired of navigating through the same 3 directories to run my program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about creating a jar file containing all your files (classes and other resources)?
A jar also has a 'default' class the main method of which gets executed when the user double clicks it or calls it using `java -jar <jar-file>`.
You can use the [Ant jar task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html).

Beside that, it is important that you keep your directory structure (outside a jar), otherwise the java class loader won't be happy when it has to load these classes. Or did I get your question wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you would use a [flatten mapper](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html#flatten-mapper), as carej points out. The [copy](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) task even has a shortcut for it:

```
<copy todir="${output}" flatten="yes">
    <fileset dir="${build}" includes="**/*.class"/>
</copy>
```

**However**, I also don't understand what you hope to accomplish with this. The java runtime expects class files to be in a directory structure that mirrors the package structure. Copying the class files to the top-level directory won't work, unless the classes are in the default package (there is no `package` statement in the `.java` files).

If you want to avoid having to manually change directories, you can always add a target to your ant build file that calls the `java` task with the appropriate classpath and other parameters. For example:

```
<target name="run" depends="compile">
    <java classname="com.crosse.samplespace.SampleProgram"
          classpath=".:build"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want to do by using the flattenmapper but I'm at a loss to understand what possible valid reason you'd have for doing it.